# Зависимости и взаимодействие элементов при перемещении

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть элемент `timeline` в который помещаются новые элементы `линии`, которые помещаются туда методом `drag and drop`. Нужно сделать чтобы эти элементы упирались друг в друга при перемещении (если левый элемент двигать вправо, и на его пути встретится правый - левый должен упереться в него и не двигаться, то есть движение в свободной области, ограниченной (или не) другими элементами). При перетаскивании элемента через другой элемент, должно происходить перескакивание через элемент, движимый элемент должен перепрыгнуть через препятствующий элемент, при достижении середины недвижимого элемента курсором с опущенной кнопкой мыши. Подскажите как это технически реализовать и куда копать?

```
$('.sossage')
        .draggable({
            axis: 'x',
            containment: 'parent',
            disabled: disable,
            start: function () {
                $('.pl-popup').hide();
                $(this).css({
                    'z-index': 1
                })
            },
            stop: function () {
                $(this).css({
                    'z-index': 0
                })
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, для какой задачи вам это нужно, но мне такое поведение элементов кажется неестественным. Т.е. ожидания пользователя будут отличаться от вашего функционала, если все сделать в точности, как вы описали.

Предлагаю никак не реагировать на препятствие на пути, а перемещать элемент над препятствиями. Обрабатывать лишь событие `.mouseup()`.

Если напишите в вопросе хоть какой-то код - проще будет понять, как именно вам лучше помочь. Или уточните, хотя бы, для чего такое поведение?

Comment: Это таймлайн. Каждый елемент - это плейлист. Путем перетаскивания елементов по таймлайну пользователь выбирает длину и время проигрывания того или иного плейлиста.
На данный момент елементы перемещают сядруг над другом и так, но нужно как-то запретить накладывание елементов друг на друга - в этом идея. Два плейлиста не могут играть в одно время. Тким образом - если отпустить плелист в то вреям как он находится над другим - должне произойти здвиг на ближайшее свободное место. В  Jquery, к примеру, есть прилепание перетаскиваемых елементов друг к другу. Интересно узнать как это реализовано.